# Are low, polar lunar orbits in general relatively stable?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, lro, mascon, chandrayaan-spacecraft

The Phys.org article [New NASA radar technique finds lost lunar spacecraft](https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-radar-technique-lost-lunar.html) describes the use of radar to relocate two spacecraft that were in orbit around the moon but who's orbit had not been actively tracked for a while.

> Finding a derelict spacecraft at lunar distance that has not been tracked for years is tricky because the moon is riddled with mascons (regions with higher-than-average gravitational pull) that can dramatically affect a spacecraft's orbit over time, and even cause it to have crashed into the moon. JPL's orbital calculations indicated that Chandrayaan-1 is still circling some 124 miles (200 kilometers) above the lunar surface, but it was generally considered "lost."

I have not found detailed information on Chandrayaan-1's orbit except that it was polar with an altitude of about [100 km](http://www.isro.gov.in/Spacecraft/chandrayaan-1) or [200 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-1). However, the LRO is seems to be in a daring 160 x 20 km orbit.

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit#Perturbation_effects) suggests there are "frozen orbits" about the moon with inclinations of  27°, 50°, 76°, and 86°, but the LRO was inserted at about 90°.

Are low, polar lunar orbits in general relatively stable compared to lower inclination orbits, or is it still necessary to maintain station keeping capability? Do stable polar orbits actively avoid [mascons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy)), or does the mascon distribution somehow "average out" for polar orbits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LRO was inserted into a polar frozen orbit for commissioning, which required no stationkeeping.  This orbit was a stable 31.5 km x 199 km polar orbit with periapsis over the South Pole.  By "frozen" they mean that the line of apsides and eccentricity remain fixed.

It then moved into a 50km circular polar orbit (+/- 20 km) for its science mission.  This orbit required a stationkeeping maneuver once a month, with a budget of about 150 m/s for the year.

Then after the mapping phase, LRO moved again into a polar frozen orbit, where no stationkeeping is required.

references:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20070021535.pdf
https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdfplus/10.2514/6.2010-1985

Circular polar orbits are *not* stable.  The orbit maintenance budget to stay in one varies significantly based on your selected insertion state- a 110 km orbit at 84 deg inclination might stay around for a year without needing a maneuver, but a 100 km orbit at 90 deg inclination can require 100 m/s annually to stay within +/- 30 km.

But there are elliptical polar frozen orbits, like the one that LRO is in, that don't need orbit maintenance.  As here: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2006-6749

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and well referenced answer! It looks like the question's linked Wikipedia discussion of "frozen" could use some polishing.

Comment: Found that LRO spends merely 2.2 kg/year on its 'Frozen orbit' maintenance  https://youtu.be/d2uaJ2xRYpc?t=450